# What's the substitution of GetPortalByAlias in DNN 7.02?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I used to use `GetPortalByAlias` function in one of my modules in DNN 6.2.6 and below.
Now I find out that in DNN 7 this function has omitted.
What's the substitution of this function in DNN 7.02?

Assume that my code is like this:

```
IDataReader dr = 
    DotNetNuke.Data.DataProvider.Instance().GetPortalByAlias(portalAlias);
```

When I want to compile the code above in DNN 7 It says:

> 'DotNetNuke.Data.DataProvider' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetPortalByAlias' and no extension method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UrlRewriteModule` uses `PortalAliasController.GetPortalAliasInfo` to do that.  I think, in general, you should shy away from using the data provider methods directly, if you can avoid it (though, in this case, the right API is a little hard to find, and wasn't available on older versions of DNN).